# Formulating a convex optimization problem as semidefinite program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality, schur-complement

I have the following minimization problem

$$\text{minimize} \quad f(x)= c^T F(x)^{-1} c$$

where $F : \mathbb R^n \to \mbox{Sym}_m (\mathbb R)$,

$$\mbox{dom} f = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid F(x) \succ 0 \}$$

and $c \in \mathbb{R}^m$. The task is to reformulate as an SDP.

I kind of know that I should use the Schur complement, but still not sure. This is my guess:

max. $ a $

s.t. $\begin{bmatrix}
F(x) & c \\
c^T & a
\end{bmatrix} \succ 0 $

Comment: If you maximize $a$, the "optimal" solution will be $\infty$. Is that what you want?  You kinda know you should use the Schur complement because someone told you to? How about working it out?

Comment: Introduce a new optimization variable and write the minimization problem in epigraph form.

Answer (score 2):

You can reformulate the problem by introducing a slack variable. Your problem is actually the following constrained optimization problem:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\min_x  & c^T F(x)^{-1}c \\
\text{subject to}& F(x)\succ 0.
\end{array}$$

By introducing a slack variable $a$, you have the following problem:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\min_{x,a}  & a \\
\text{subject to} & F(x) \succ 0 \\
& c^\top F(x)^{-1} c \leq a. 
\end{array}$$

As you mentioned, you can apply the Schur complement to reformulate the two constraints as a single matrix inequality:
$$\begin{cases}
F(x) \succ 0 \\
c^\top F(x)^{-1}c - a \leq 0 
\end{cases}
\Rightarrow 
\begin{bmatrix}
F(x) & c \\ c^\top & a 
\end{bmatrix} \succ 0$$

Hence, your problem can be reformulated as an optimization problem with a matrix inequality constraint:
$$\begin{array}{ll}
\min_{x,a}  & a \\
\text{subject to} & \begin{bmatrix}
F(x) & c \\ c^\top & a 
\end{bmatrix} \succ 0. 
\end{array}$$

If the function $F(x)$ is affine in $x$, the constraint becomes a linear matrix inequality in decision variables $x$ and $a$. Therefore, the reformulated problem is an SDP.